# Accessing StreamProvider anywhere in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, stream

I am still learning flutter/Dart and creating an app in the process.

Now, I am looking at my code and thinking that I am working too hard by not using some StreamProviders I create in my main.dart file. I did this at the very beginning of my journey so I really didn't know what I was doing. I was just following a tutorial.

So, in my main.dart I created a multiprovider and some StreamProviders inside that.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firestoreService = FirestoreService();

    Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
    
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AgentProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AgencyProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TrxnProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => EventProvider()),
        // The following providers are for retrieving the data for editing purposes
        // The stream providers are only called once but they can be accessed
        // anywhere in the app.
        StreamProvider(create: (context) => firestoreService.getAgents(), initialData: []),
        StreamProvider(create: (context) => firestoreService.getAgency(), initialData: []),
        StreamProvider(
            create: (context) => firestoreService.getAgencyTrxns(context),  initialData: []),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoginScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you can see, I added notes stating that I can access the streams anywhere in my code but I have been creating new streams throughout. Yes, this is embarrassing but I am learning.

Here are the 3 functions used to create the StreamProviders above

```
 Stream<List<Agents>> getAgents() {
    return _db.collection('agents').snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Agents.fromFirestore(document.data()))
        .toList());
  }

  Stream<List<Agency>> getAgency() {
    return _db.collection('agency').snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Agency.fromFirestore(document.data()))
        .toList());
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAgencyTrxns(BuildContext context) async* {
    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId)
        .collection('trxns')
        .where('trxnStatus', isNotEqualTo: 'Closed')
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Had I realized what I have done it would have saved me a lot of work...I think.

Now, I am trying to learn how to use these StreamProviders in my code. How do I use them in a StreamBuilder? Currently, this is what I am doing and I don't think I am using the StreamProviders I create in my main.dart.

```
child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: _db.collection('agency').snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        } else {
```

I think I need to use consume. I am watching a YouTube video but it is not very clear. I would really like to use the StreamProviders I already have rather than create new streams and use memory.

Any help you can provide or if you can point me to a great tutorial that would be even better.